# How to create pointer chains? I would like to create objects that have pointers pointing to further objects, that has pointers. Is this even possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, chain

I've created this example code, but I just can't make it work. I want to create children from a parent node, in a way that every children has one parent, and each have a pointer to its parent. The first parent's pointer is the nullpointer. Now the question is, if I am somewhere at the end of the tree's branch, how can I return to the first parent step by step, and write out the history?

For the sake of simplicity, in this example I've created a linear graph with one simple path.

I discovered that if I want to dereference a node's parent's node for the second time, I already get fake results, and I can't reach further than the first parent. So I can only dereference the current node's parent. Why is that? I have seen that in linked-lists people store every pointer, but I would like to avoid that. The goal is, every node is stored in a `list<Node>`,  and each of them stores only its parents pointer, so from every node we can trace back the first parent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int node;
    Node *parent;
};

void create (Node parent, list<Node>& graph)
{
    if (graph.size() < 10)
    {
        Node nn;
        nn.node = parent.node+1;
        nn.parent = &parent;
        graph.push_back(nn);
        create(nn, graph);
    }
}

int main()
{
    list<Node> graph;

    Node parent;
    parent.node = 0;
    parent.parent = nullptr;
    graph.push_back(parent);

    create(parent, graph);

    for (auto i : graph)
    {
        cout << i.node << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    auto it = graph.begin();
    advance(it, 3);

    cout << (*it).node << endl;
    cout << (*(*(*it).parent).parent).node;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many nodes do you think are in that list?

Comment: You can just keep adding `*`s but, as Beta points out, this doesn't scale very well. I recommend a re-think. Perhaps a loop?

Comment: Reason for the fake results: In `void create (Node parent, list<Node>& graph)`, `parent` [is passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). This means it's a copy of the argument and a local variable that will expire at the end of the function. Keeping a pointer to this value leaves you with what's called a [Dangling Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). Instead pass `parent` by reference: `void create (Node & parent, list<Node>& graph)`.

Comment: `(*it).node` -> `it->node`, `(*(*(*it).parent).parent).node` -> `it->parent->parent->node`

Comment: if you really want a structure where pointers are stored recursively, and you have thought about it and it's a good idea, the method of accesing these structures usually wants to be a recursive function as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `Node`s as local variables in the `create` function. When you exit function's scope, addresses you save as `Node`s' `parent` won't contain the `Node` which was previously there (every `nn.parent` becomes a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_dangling_pointers)).

If you wish to create `Node`s in a function, it should look something like this:

```
void create(Node* parent, list<Node>& graph)
{
    if (graph.size() < 10)
    {
        Node* nn = new Node;
        nn->node = parent->node + 1;
        nn->parent = parent;
        graph.push_back(*nn);
        create(nn, graph);
    }
}
```

This, however, will cause several problems:

1. In this line `graph.push_back(*nn);` we are dereferencing `nn` which leads to unnecessary copying of `int` and `Node*` (struct attributes) values.
2. We are causing a memory leak since we are not saving `nn` value anywhere, so we can't delete its content later.

It would be better to keep a list of `Node*` instead of `Node`:

```
list<Node*> graph;
```

That way, we could just iterate through the list and delete dynamically allocated `Node`s later on:

```
for (auto i : graph)
    delete i;
```

And instead of copying `int` and `Node*` values, we just push `Node* nn` to the list:

```
graph.push_back(nn);
```

---

> Note that `it` is a pointer to a pointer now, so it would require double dereferencing:
>
> ```
> cout << (**it).node << endl;
> cout << (*(*(**it).parent).parent).node;
> ```